# Asus A455LJ brightness Fn+F5+F6 doesn't work on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, brightness, asus, shortcuts

i've just installed ubuntu 16.04 on my asus A455LJ i5 5200u with Nvidia 920m, and just install nvidia driver properly but i can't get my brightness control Fn+F5 nor Fn+F6 work, but in the system setting i can slide the brightness manualy.

i've use evtest on asus WMI hotkey and get this list

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x19 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
Input device name: "Asus WMI hotkeys"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    Event code 140 (KEY_CALC)
    Event code 148 (KEY_PROG1)
    Event code 150 (KEY_WWW)
    Event code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG)
    Event code 164 (KEY_PLAYPAUSE)
    Event code 165 (KEY_PREVIOUSSONG)
    Event code 166 (KEY_STOPCD)
    Event code 169 (KEY_PHONE)
    Event code 185 (KEY_F15)
    Event code 191 (KEY_F21)
    Event code 212 (KEY_CAMERA)
    Event code 215 (KEY_EMAIL)
    Event code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN)
    Event code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP)
    Event code 226 (KEY_MEDIA)
    Event code 227 (KEY_SWITCHVIDEOMODE)
    Event code 229 (KEY_KBDILLUMDOWN)
    Event code 230 (KEY_KBDILLUMUP)
    Event code 237 (KEY_BLUETOOTH)
    Event code 238 (KEY_WLAN)
    Event code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN)
    Event code 245 (KEY_DISPLAY_OFF)
    Event code 247 (KEY_RFKILL)
    Event code 431 (KEY_DISPLAYTOGGLE)
    Event code 531 (KEY_TOUCHPAD_ON)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Key repeat handling:
  Repeat type 20 (EV_REP)
    Repeat code 0 (REP_DELAY)
      Value    250
    Repeat code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
      Value     33
```

actually all the button work except for Fn+ F5/F6, evtest didn't listen anything. Hope someone get me out from this bug. :3

Comment: Boot with `acpi_osi=` kernel parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried doing it with the Fn+f5/f6 shortcut, but any other
key worked this way for me:

In terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

go to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts:

Add this two commands with the "+" button:

```
xbacklight -inc 10 # brighter

xbacklight -inc 10 # dimmer
```

Finally, give them any name and shortcut you wish.